# Amazon EFS: Changing Wordpress upload directory to outside root

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, amazon-efs

I have multiple AWS EC2 instances which are updated from a Git repository via CodeDeploy. However, since keeping the `wp-content/uploads` folder in Git is messy and hard to maintain, I'm instead trying to move all uploads to a directory which I have mounted as an EFS filesystem. That way I should be able to share the uploads between multiple EC2 instances.

However, now I'm running into a new problem; there's no way for me to set the WP uploads folder to be outside of the WP root.

WordPress is located at `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`, which is also where our domain points. The EFS system is mounted to `/home/bitnami/efs`. Since the EFS directory is located outside of the WP root there's no way for me to link to it.

I have gotten this to work using a symlink directing the default `wp-content/uploads` folder to my desired path; however, this doesn't really solve my issue since I can't rely on the symlink to not be overwritten during CodeDeploy deployments.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to have this setup work without using a symlink, so I can make deployments without worrying about by uploads being affected?
2. If a symlink is the only/best way to make this work, is there any way to add the symlink to the git repository, or any other way to make absolutely sure it persists during CodeDeploy deployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly mount your EFS to `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads` to avoid symlinks.

In your `appspec.yml` add two hooks:

```
hooks:
    BeforeInstall:
      - location: /deploy/BeforeInstall.sh
        timeout: 3000
        runas: root
    AfterInstall:
      - location: /deploy/AfterInstall.sh
        timeout: 3000
        runas: root
```

Then create directory `deploy` and two files in it `BeforeInstall.sh` and `AfterInstall.sh`

`BeforeInstall.sh` unmount the EFS if its mounted

```
#!/bin/bash
if mount | grep /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads > /dev/null; then
    sudo umount /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads
fi
```

Then mount EFS again via `AfterInstall.sh` after deployment

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 fs-fxxxxxx.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/ /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads
```

Note: You can also mount entire `wp-contents` directory, not just `uploads` folder, so that update in `themes` and `plugins` also get reflected in other EC2s automatically.

Also, symlink is a better solution, so you don't have to ever worry about accidentally removing the EFS mount during deployment if `umount` ever fails. You can just recreate symlink again after deployment using `AfterInstall` hook and add code in file `AfterInstall.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -s /home/bitnami/efs /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads
```

Comment: Thanks! Your last code sample is actually very close to what I ended up doing. For some reason, CodeDeploy seems to sometimes empty out the directory before deploying, and sometimes skip that step. So, if the symlink was still there during an attempted deployment, the `AfterInstall.sh` script would fail. I fixed this by changing the `-s` flag to `-sfn` when creating the symlink - this way, if the symlink already exists, it will simply be recreated rather than cause the whole deployment to fail.

Now it seems my deployments are pretty fail-safe. Thanks for the help!!